# How to add new field in Add new Customers in Admin Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I want to add new field in Add new customers in Magento admin.
Customers-> All customers-> Add new customers,

Refer my screenshot.[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: I have tried to override the vendor module (module-customer) but  I am not to identify the basic structure of the form, as all the fields are binded from the different files

Comment: Create new attribute that will automatically added here.

Answer (score 0):

when creating the attribute programatically, be sure to set the correct values for `used_in_forms`

In this case you need to have `adminhtml_customer` in the array